# How can we select items that match a specific pattern from a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have dates that look like this: `2019-12-20`

I tried this, and got nothing returned.

```
df_values = df[df['load_date'].isin(['-12-'])]
```

Also, tried this, and got nothing returned.

```
df_values  = df[df.load_date.isin(['-12-'])]
```

How can we select items that match a specific pattern from a column in a dataframe? Oh, and the datatype is object.

Comment: Just convert the date to datetime and find where month is equal to 12: `df['load_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['load_date']); df[df['load_date'].dt.month == 12]`

Comment: Do you want match only December dates? Try `df['load_date'].dt.month.eq(12)`

Comment: Thanks! It works! I can't believe I didn't see that before!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use series.str.contains
below is the code.

```
df_values = df['load_date'].str.contains("-12-",regex=True)
```